# Can I edit cocos2d-iphone template (v 0.99.2)

Tags: templates, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to iPhone development. I am using cocos2d 0.99.2 templates with xcode. Is it possible for me to make changes to these templates, like removing comments or adding some code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You probably want to make a copy of the template before you start editing it though.